# Can I use an Android emulator to access GWT app running in Dev Mode?

Tags: gwt, android-emulator

How can I debug a GWT app (in GWT Dev Mode) using a browser on an Android device or emulator?

Details follow:

I am trying to use deferred binding to serve up a different view for mobile devices.  I'm creating a proof of concept app app based on the [GWT MobileWebApp sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/mobilewebapp/src/com/google/gwt/sample/mobilewebapp/?r=10041).

I have installed the Android SDK and plugin in Eclipse.  When I launch the Android emulator and input my URL the mobile webkit browser hits my GWT app (running in Eclipse) but complains about not having the GWT Developer Plugin.  Doh!

Is compiling and running in Production Mode my only option?  How can I debug?

Ideas and input greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks so much for the link to the sample application. I saw Chris Ramsdale made a demo on this but I couldn't find the application's code.

Comment: houman001, let me know if you are able to get the GWT MobileWebApp sample working.  unfortunately, i was not able to get past the error described here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054472/http-error-500-no-realm-running-gwts-mobilewebapp-sample).  I suspect lack of App Engine experience may have been my problem.  any suggestions would be most appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no GWT Development Mode plugin for Android (emulated or otherwise). Minimize your compile time by limiting to the Android `user.agent` property to make testing easier.

Comment: I believe there's been an Android plugin in the work at Google, but either they never finished it, or they finally thought they don't need it. (I doubt they'd keep it private if they made it working)